# Fetching more 100000 rows in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am currently using Cassandra 1.6.6, however I having a big problem.  I am trying to fetch more than 100000 rows using the LIMIT clause, however I always get the error below and then the database just shutdown.

TSocket read 0 bytes.

Secondly, does any know how to update all the rows in a Cassandra database.

Thanks awaiting your reply. I just can't find anything online, very distress.

Answer (score 0):

TSocket read 0 bytes means you lost the connection to Cassandra, possibly due to the timeout that stops running a malformed query that would cause system instability. I don't think you can run one query that updates all rows because you need to specify the unique key to update a row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can you minimize timeout in Cassandra. What is the maximum amount of rows that Cassandra can fetch at any given time.

Comment: In the cassandra.yaml, you set the various timeouts. The one of interest to you is read_request_timeout_in_ms, I think. 
(Default: 10000) The time in milliseconds that the coordinator waits for read operations to complete. Good luck. The cqlsh shell has a default row limit of 10,000. The Cassandra server and native protocol do not limit the number of rows that can be returned.

Comment: Very good, this worked perfectly for me. I've updated read_request_timeout_ms to 20000 and my query with limit 200,000 runs without problems. Thank you!